# Coexistence and migration to Dovecot

Tags: dovecot, maildir, imapsync

We have an environment with >5,000 mailboxes and we need to coexist/migrate the emails from one dovecot to another dovecot environment.

The migration data includes:

- email (sync using imapsync)
- contacts
- calendars
- tasks
- Mail filter (inbox rules)
- Autoresponders

For email, we can develop a tool to sync/migrate the imapsync, but the following is still unknown:

- Coexistence proxy. Connection connects to a "dovecot proxy" and if the user is migrated, it will redirect to the new environment; if user is non-migrated, it will redirect to the old environment
- Sync tool for the other data as above (contacts, calendars, etc).

Any idea what tools should we use for us to build the migration process? As we have so many users, it is mandatory to do a phase migration (means it needs to co-exist).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a proxy, consider doing presyncs and parallelism. After the first long presync, all others will be quicker and you will even know how long the last sync will take. Read

- https://imapsync.lamiral.info/FAQ.d/FAQ.Migration_Plan.txt
- https://imapsync.lamiral.info/FAQ.d/FAQ.Massive.txt

Comment: This Gilles. In fact your tool is something that we are thinking of using to do the IMAP migration.